# Minecraft skins for Windows 10 and Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My granddaughter has been playing Minecraft on her iphone/ipad for quite a long time now and has accumulated a ton of skins.  She just got a new laptop for her birthday and I purchased the PC version of Minecraft for that as well.  I understand that they are two different platforms of the game however, the pocket version gives you the option to export skins.  My question is:  can the skins be exported from the pocket edition (on the iphone or ipad) to the PC version?  I am thinking no but it doesn't hurt to ask those that know more about it than I do!  Thanks!

Comment: Which PC edition? Windows 10 or Java?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because it's not quite enough for an answer… Skins on the PC version (from Minecraft.net) are free. You have to Goto Minecraft.net and to your profile to upload a skin and it will take effect immediately. If your on the windows 10 beta, however, it will be the same as pocket edition. So you should be able to transport skins if you have an Xbox account connected to the two. It might require Xbox live or Xbox gold to do that, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think yes, they both use the same skin file, so it shouldn't be a problem to do that.

Comment: You think? Or do you *Know?*